# Перебор вложенных массивов и подсчет одинаковых значений первых элементов вложенных массивов. Застрял :(

Tags: javascript, массивы

Всем добрый день!
Застрял с задачей :( Понимаю что откровенно туплю, но я не большой спец в JS, поэтому не понимаю что не так.
Важный момент: код должен соответствовать ES4.
Есть массив с вложенными массивами строк (привожу фрагмент):

```
var bigArray = [
    ["02.01.01.02.Формирование программы","Ответственный за формирование Программы ","Формирование/ Корректировка  Программы ","Исполнитель"],
    ["02.01.01.02. Формирование программы","Ответственный за формирование Программы","Проведение совещания по рассмотрению и утверждению Программы","Консультант"],
    ["02.01.01.04. Корректировка годовой инвестиционной программы","Куратор статьи ИП","Формирование комментариев  по отклонениям ИП","Исполнитель"],
    ["02.01.01.05. Разработка квартальных инвестиционных программ","Куратор статьи ИП","Формирование плана на  следующий квартал","Исполнитель"],
    ["02.01.01.05. Разработка квартальных инвестиционных программ","Куратор статьи ИП","Консолидация проекта  квартального плана","Консультант"],
    ["02.01.02.02. Мониторинг инвестиционной программы","Куратор статьи ИП","Проведение  ежеквартального мониторинга","Консультант"],
    ["02.01.02.02. Мониторинг инвестиционной программы","Куратор статьи ИП","Формирование месячного отчета по  фактическому исполнению  по направлению","Исполнитель"],
    ["02.01.02.02. Мониторинг инвестиционной программы","Куратор статьи ИП","Проведение анализа  изменений лимитов инвестиций","Консультант"],
    ["02.01.02.02. Мониторинг инвестиционной программы","Куратор статьи ИП","Проведение анализа  изменения объемных  показателей за год","Консультант"]];
```

Нужно перебирая массив подсчитывать количество равных первых элементов вложенных массивов, после нахождения полной серии равных элементов выдавать (в данном примере для простоты - выводить) значение счетчика,  обнулять счетчик, искать следующую серию и так до конца массива.
Количество серий, их длина - непостоянные.

Я пока придумал такое:

```js
var bigArray = [
  ["02.01.01.02.Формирование программы", "Ответственный за формирование Программы ", "Формирование/ Корректировка  Программы ", "Исполнитель"],
  ["02.01.01.02. Формирование программы", "Ответственный за формирование Программы", "Проведение совещания по рассмотрению и утверждению Программы", "Консультант"],
  ["02.01.01.04. Корректировка годовой инвестиционной программы", "Куратор статьи ИП", "Формирование комментариев  по отклонениям ИП", "Исполнитель"],
  ["02.01.01.05. Разработка квартальных инвестиционных программ", "Куратор статьи ИП", "Формирование плана на  следующий квартал", "Исполнитель"],
  ["02.01.01.05. Разработка квартальных инвестиционных программ", "Куратор статьи ИП", "Консолидация проекта  квартального плана", "Консультант"],
  ["02.01.02.02. Мониторинг инвестиционной программы", "Куратор статьи ИП", "Проведение  ежеквартального мониторинга", "Консультант"],
  ["02.01.02.02. Мониторинг инвестиционной программы", "Куратор статьи ИП", "Формирование месячного отчета по  фактическому исполнению  по направлению", "Исполнитель"],
  ["02.01.02.02. Мониторинг инвестиционной программы", "Куратор статьи ИП", "Проведение анализа  изменений лимитов инвестиций", "Консультант"],
  ["02.01.02.02. Мониторинг инвестиционной программы", "Куратор статьи ИП", "Проведение анализа  изменения объемных  показателей за год", "Консультант"]
];

var k = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < bigArray.length; i++) {
  if ((i == bigArray.length - 1) && (bigArray[i][0] == bigArray[i + 1][0])) {
    k++;
    console.log("Найдена серия длиной: " + k);
    break;
  } else if ((i == bigArray.length - 1) && (bigArray[i][0] != bigArray[i + 1][0])) {
    k = 1;
    console.log("Найдена серия длиной: " + k);
    break;
  } else if (bigArray[i][0] == bigArray[i + 1][0]) {
    k++;
  } else {
    k++;
    console.log("Найдена серия длиной: " + k);
    k = 0;
  }
}
```

Но, во-первых, скрипт при дохождении до последнего вложенного массива выпадает в ошибку `"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')"` и я пока не понимаю почему, а во-вторых есть четкое ощущение что есть более лаконичный и красивый вариант этого кода.
Ожидаемый результат для приведенного в качестве примера фрагмента массива:

```
Найдена серия длиной: 2
Найдена серия длиной: 1
Найдена серия длиной: 2
Найдена серия длиной: 4
```

Comment: `i < bigArray.length - 1`

Comment: Но в этом случае ведь не обрабатывается последняя серия

Comment: почему ты так думаешь?

Comment: Точнее, не "не обрабатывается", а не выводится значение счетчика.
Вот текущий код:
`
var k = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < bigArray.length-1; i++) { 
остальное без изменений

}
`
Вот вывод:
`
i = 0
i = 1
Найдена серия длиной: 2
i = 2
Найдена серия длиной: 1
i = 3
i = 4
Найдена серия длиной: 2
i = 5
i = 6
i = 7
`

Comment: А какой вообще результат ты ожидаешь от своего кода?

Comment: Мне нужны эти самые "выводы" значений счетчиков длины серий. Я их буду дальше использовать в коде. Т.е. вместо "найдена серия длиной  XX"", это самое "ХХ" будет передаваться из функции. А сейчас у меня не отлавливается значение счетчика длины последней серии в массиве.

Comment: Добавь в вопрос пример результата, который ты хочешь получить для текущих входных данных

Comment: Готово, сделал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы наверняка ожидаете чего-то такого.

Все вроде соответствует стандарту ES4.

```js
var bigArray = [
  ["02.01.01.02.Формирование программы", "Ответственный за формирование Программы ", "Формирование/ Корректировка  Программы ", "Исполнитель"],
  ["02.01.01.02.Формирование программы", "Ответственный за формирование Программы", "Проведение совещания по рассмотрению и утверждению Программы", "Консультант"],
  ["02.01.01.04. Корректировка годовой инвестиционной программы", "Куратор статьи ИП", "Формирование комментариев  по отклонениям ИП", "Исполнитель"],
  ["02.01.01.05. Разработка квартальных инвестиционных программ", "Куратор статьи ИП", "Формирование плана на  следующий квартал", "Исполнитель"],
  ["02.01.01.05. Разработка квартальных инвестиционных программ", "Куратор статьи ИП", "Консолидация проекта  квартального плана", "Консультант"],
  ["02.01.02.02. Мониторинг инвестиционной программы", "Куратор статьи ИП", "Проведение  ежеквартального мониторинга", "Консультант"],
  ["02.01.02.02. Мониторинг инвестиционной программы", "Куратор статьи ИП", "Формирование месячного отчета по  фактическому исполнению  по направлению", "Исполнитель"],
  ["02.01.02.02. Мониторинг инвестиционной программы", "Куратор статьи ИП", "Проведение анализа  изменений лимитов инвестиций", "Консультант"],
  ["02.01.02.02. Мониторинг инвестиционной программы", "Куратор статьи ИП", "Проведение анализа  изменения объемных  показателей за год", "Консультант"]
];

function count(array) {
  var counter = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    if (array[i][0] == array[i + 1][0]) {
      counter++;
      continue;
    }
    console.log("Найдена серия длиной: " + (counter));
    counter = 1;
  }
  console.log("Найдена серия длиной: " + (counter))
}

count(bigArray);
```

Comment: а зачем массив, если надо только количество считать

Comment: @Grundy, действительно, зачем? Исправил, зафиксировался на массивах.

Comment: `if (!array[i + 1]) continue;` - нужно для отсечения последней итерации, почему просто в проверке не уменьшить на единицу?

Comment: @Grundy хорошее замечание.

Comment: @Grundy, нет, не только количество считать. Информация из массива потом в таблицу пойдет. А считать надо, чтобы объединение строк в таблице сделать.

Comment: @Neverm1ndo, большое спасибо! Завтра изучу и опробую

Comment: @Mangol, не вижу связи. Ну и если ты хотел сгруппировать массив по какому либо полю - то делать надо было совсем по другому :-)

Comment: @Grundy, очень может быть :( В вопросе я привел только кусок задачи. Мне этот массив надо вывести в таблицу с объединенными ячейками строк.  Я планировал значения счетчика подавать как параметр метода, рисующего ячейку. Т.е. запустили цикл подсчета серии, получили первое значение счетчика, отрисовали кусок  таблицы, запустили еще раз, получили следующее значение, отрисовали еще раз. 
Массив предварительно отсортирован, так что осталось только выводить.

Comment: @Mangol, какую задачу описал - на такую тебе и дали решение ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ В следующий раз  описывай именно ту задачу, которую хочешь решить.

Comment: @Grundy, так у меня 0 претензий. Ответ на свой вопрос я получил.  Код Neverm1ndo отлично работает. 
Поэтому мне остается только сказать всем большое спасибо за помощь!